# Porting Any OS - Where do I start?

Tags: porting

What things must be done in order to begin with porting? Is there any documentation or something that will help me understand the steps of OS porting ?

Comment: Partial answer, so in the comments.

- Port/write a bootloader for your device.

- Port the Android version of Linux kernel on your device including the drivers. This part is more related to Linux kernel then to Android.

- When kernel is starting successfully, I would try to burn the Android partitions and run it, solving issues if any. And of cause look into the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/index.html) is the mirror of what you want to find. But can  you specify what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [this](http://www.anddev.org/learning_porting_android_to_real_device_step_by_step-t3252.html) is what you're looking for as things differ based on the platform, but it's a step in the right direction if you're interested in Linux hardware. As mentioned in your other link the [Android x-86](http://www.android-x86.org/) stuff is also a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what you are trying to port. If you want to [port Cyanogenmod](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_porting_intro) or port [MIUI](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/guide-build-port-miui-rom-to-device-t3250984) or from [Here](http://en.miui.com/thread-13737-1-1.html) too, If just any rom, You can replace the files from the stock of your phone, with the new files from the wanted Rom.

- If you are using ubuntu, & wanna port a rom which is Android 5.0+, You will need a package called `android-tools-fsutils` which can be installed by running `sudo apt-get install android-tools-fsutils` , to extract `img` files

**NOTE :** `img` files in android are not the same as the `img` files supported by ISO apps & unrar apps. Specific tools are needed.

If you want to port Ubuntu Touch, [This](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/) will help.

You need to learn about the **Kernel** of any OS , it's how the OS interacts with hardware, Makes it boot & controls the hardware e.g CPU clock speed / GPU clock speed.

You need to learn about filsystems as well, maybe a scripting language like perl/python will be enough but it's not obligatory, you can continue your rough way, a scripting language will turn things easy.

Actually, I saw this question right now while I'm downloading cyanogen source to try to port , I don't know how actually, but I know about cpus/kernel & some programming languages. So, I think I will make it. You will find many words that you may not understand, Don't ignore.

**ALWAYS** try to learn every word you see, Know how apps interact with the RAM/CPU/GPU/BOARD/HDD , Know shortcuts e.g GPU > Graphics Processing Unit, This will help in trying to understand everything & will prevent your brain from mixing shortcuts like CPU/GPU/APU .

there's just something to say, If you are afraid to do something in your device & scared of failing to fix it after that, This is the 1st thing that will make you **FAIL**. So, Try on a device that you can leave it not working for days, Trying to make it work.